# Чи існують україномовні аналоги таблиць Снеллена або Головіна — Сівцева

Tags: переклад

Чи існують україномовні аналоги таблиць [Снеллена](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), [Головіна — Сівцева](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F_%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) або подібних?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Я бачив у Інтернеті «українізований» варіант таблиці Сівцева: в ньому всі російські «и», окрім однієї (лівої в третьому рядку), замінені на українські «і», а всі «ы» — на «и». Я не знаю, як продуманість нової версії співвідноситься з продуманістю оригінальної (все-таки «і» легше відрізнити від більш «квадратних» літер; хоча оригінальна, може, теж не була повністю продуманою).

Приклади:

1. О. В. Заболотний, В. В. Заболотний, «Українська мова. Підручник для 5 класу загальноосвітніх навчальних закладів», Київ, «Генеза», 2003 наводить часткове фото такої таблиці у завданні 190 [на сторінці 93](https://www.slideshare.net/5klas/5-79534271#93).
2. Різні варіанти  акомодаційних лінійок Коваленка ЛА-А і ЛА-С ідуть у комплекті з такою таблицею. Сама акомодаційна лінійка є сертифікованою.
   Приклади з ілюстраціями: [інтернет-магазин 1](//dary-makoshi.com.ua/site_search?search_term=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE), [інтернет-магазин 2](http://linza.if.ua/index.php?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE&submit_search=), [інтернет-магазин 3](//ceny.by/minsk/search/detskiy-mir/prochie-detskie-tovary/linejka-akkomodacionnaja-kovalenko-la-s-sfericheskaja-025-05-075--61440.html).

Зображення (перепрошую за якість, довелося розвертати і вирізати зайве, щоб була лише таблиця; для зображень вищої якості перейдіть за посиланнями у другому пункті):

[image: «Українізована» таблиця Сівцева]

Comment: @Follower, лінійка, з логотипом. Теоретично використання такого зображення може підпадати під копірайт. Хоча теортично це в будь-якому разі є порушенням.

Answer (score 6):

Не памʼятаю україномовнї, переважно совєцькі Головіна, Сївцева (доволї часто зустрічав, плюс незалежна від мови), також Орлової (рідко, рисунки для дїтей). Наразї для якісної перевірки — застаріла технолоґія [хоч і актуальна для «ловлї початкових поганозрячих»] — для цього є електрична технїка [назву не знаю, типу дивишся на змінний малюнок]. Щоправда, я не перевіряв себе давно.

Щодо можливостї існування альтернатив.

[image]
<sup>↳ [Мережевий магазин](https://kiev.all.biz/en/sivtsev-golovins-table-orlova-and-landolts-ring-g12004512). Щоправда, виглядає вельми рекламно, отже і ненатурально. Взагалї без *ы* та *і*, переважно замінили *ы* на *и*.</sup>

[image]
<sup>↳Також [мережевий магазин](https://www.olx.ua/uk/obyavlenie/tablits-dlya-perevrki-gostroti-zoru-IDtp9qy.html), але там є реальна світлина товару. Замість *ы* — *е*.</sup>